# Custom font in WebView React Native

Tags: android, react-native, fonts

I'm using a `WebView` to show some text with proper justification (`Android` doesn't support justification). I'm exhausted trying to apply my custom font in `WebView` text `style`. I've tried the code below but no result:

```
var html = `<h1 style="font-family: MyFont"> some text here </h1>`
<WebView
  source={{html}}
  style={{width: 200, height: 200}}
/>
```

This is my `react native` file structure:

```
Project
  -android
  -node_modules 
  -...
  -assets
   --fonts
    ---MyFont.ttf
```

`MyFont.ttf` is located inside `Project/assets/fonts/`. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943384/using-custom-fonts-in-react-native-webview) too but can't get it to work. it says i should set the `baseUrl` but i don't know what `url` to set. Please help me I really need a comprehensive and working example.

Comment: do you find any solution ? I am also stuck at this place.

Comment: @Sujit nope. i guess it's just not possible !

Comment: I managed to set the font using font-face. So I created style.css file. Added font-face which contain font-family and src. Then I added css font properties to respective tag.