# How to set custom fonts in WebView(react-native-webview) in iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-webview

I want to set custom fonts in Webview. I have implemented the below code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Poppins-Bold'; 
    src:url('file:///android_asset/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf') format('truetype')
}
body{
    font-family: Poppins-Bold
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: red;
}
```

It works fine in android, but it does **not working in iOS**. Let me know if anybody has a solution for this.

> **Note: I don't want to use google's CSS font**

Comment: **immodi** did you solve this issue? I'm running into the same problem

Comment: @German, sorry mate, I couldn't find any solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

1. Set the following font URL based on platform:

   ```js
   const fontUrl = Platform.select({
       ios: "Poppins-Bold.ttf",
       android: "file:///android_asset/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf",
   });
   ```
2. Update your CSS styles to the following:

   ```js
    const css = `
        @font-face {
           font-family: 'Poppins-Bold'; 
           src: local('Poppins-Bold') url('${fontUrl}') format('truetype')
        }
        body {
           font-family: Poppins-Bold
           margin: 0;
           padding: 0;
           color: red;
        }`
   ```

   - Note that `format('truetype')` is used since your font extension is `ttf`. If you're using an `eot` font you'll need to use `format('opentype')`.
3. Once you do that, update your `WebView` component with the following props:

   ```js
   <WebView 
       source={{ html, baseUrl: '' }}
       originWhitelist={["*"]}
   />
   ```

   - Setting `baseUrl` to blank will ensure fonts are loaded. Reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943384/using-custom-fonts-in-react-native-webview) post.
   - Without setting `originWhitelist`, you'll get errors on iOS that the URL cannot be found.

This worked for me on both Android & iOS and I happen to be using Poppins as well

Comment: Thanks for update. I will check this solution. I think your code make sense.

Comment: This solution worked, although I had to remove the `local()` part in the `src` of `@font-face`.

Comment: I couldn't get this solution to work for me on iOS

Comment: `src: url('${fontUrl}') format('truetype');`

removing the local part worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution outlined by `German`  but this didn't work for me.

The only thing that got it working for me was by base64 encoding the font (you can use the service [here](https://transfonter.org/)), and injecting it that way, which is really annoying but it works across iOS and Android:

```
const pageHtml = `
      <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <style>
              @font-face {
                font-family: 'Canela'; 
                src: url('data:font/woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,${CANELA_BASE_64}') format('woff');
              }
h1, h2, h3, html, body { font-family: Canela; }
</style>
          </head>
          <body>
          ${props.html}
          </body>
        </html>
      `;
```

Then you can set up the WebView like this:

```
const webViewSource = { html: pageHtml, baseUrl: '' };
return (
   <WebView
      source={webViewSource}
      originWhitelist={['*']}
   />
);
```