# How change font-family (font-family.ttf from assets) of react-native webview

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-webview

I am using `react-native webview` to display some web content in my
`react-native` app. and my app `font-family` and `webview` `font-family` is different.
I want to change `webview font-family` from app.

Is there any method to change `font-family` of `webview` (custom-font-from-assets-directory), please help me.. Thanks

Comment: try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943384/using-custom-fonts-in-react-native-webview

Comment: tried, not working.

Comment: you can change in your web font for a quick fix

Answer (score 4):

you can achieve this, by injecting java script in-to your web-view

i.e.

injecting following code into web view which will change body tag fontFamily

```
const INJECTED_JAVASCRIPT = `(function() {
   let body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
  body.style.fontFamily = "Courier New";
})();`;
```

Web View Componenet

```
<WebView
        source={{ uri: 'https://reactnative.dev' }}
        onLoadEnd={()=>console.log('Successfuly Loaded')}
        injectedJavaScript={INJECTED_JAVASCRIPT}
        onError={syntheticEvent => {
          const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent;
          console.warn('WebView error: ', nativeEvent);
        }}
      />
```

Working Example [Link](https://snack.expo.io/@roxs.zj/29c55b)

Comment: I need to use font(.ttf) from local directory

Comment: you can not use local fonts from mobile and use them in you hosted web site. for this you need to host .ttf file somewhere and load it in your css

Comment: ttf file inside my asset folder

Comment: from assets you can not use in web-view for that you need to host it in dropbox or google drive and then inject it in javascript