# How to update Webview font family and size

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm displaying the HTML content in webview and trying to have it use the font file used in the app. I saw this example but it didnt work for me:
[Using custom fonts in React native Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943384/using-custom-fonts-in-react-native-webview)

Am I missing anything is there another way to do it ?

```
var css = `
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family: ''open-sans-bold'';
            fontSize: 19;
            src: url('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf')
        }
    </style>
</head>`;

var htmlContent = `${css}
<h1 style='font-family:BYekan'>Header</h1>
<p style='font-family:BYekan'>Some Text</p>
`

<WebView 
   style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }} 
   source={{ html: htmlContent }} 
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined your font as `''open-sans-bold''` (with double single quotes ? Why ?) and you use `style='font-family:BYekan'`

Good font-face

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'BYekan';
 fontSize: 19;
 src: url('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf')
}
```